# Where to locate an aws_iam_instance_profile in aws console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Because of a timeout issue, terraform failed to create an ec2 instance.

In order to recover from it I have manually removed the ec2 instance from aws console as well as the terraform state file.

However now it tried to recreate

```
  + aws_iam_instance_profile.server
      id:                                        <computed>
      arn:                                       <computed>
      create_date:                               <computed>
      name:                                      "server-profile"
      path:                                      "/"
      role:                                      "server-role"
      roles.#:                                   <computed>
      unique_id:                                 <computed>
```

Therefore I want to locate it in the aws console and remove it. However I don't know where to find it.

Where can I locate `aws_iam_instance_profile.server`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to IAM in the console and then Roles.

You should be able to find the role there, once you delete that, the instance profile should also be gone.

Comment: It does not exist in `Roles`. It is `aws_iam_instance_profile`, not `aws_iam_role`

Comment: An instance profile is basically just a role that is applied to an instance. Can you not find server-role in IAM > Roles?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_manage_delete.html

Alternatively, you can easily delete the instance profile via AWS CLI:
```aws iam delete-instance-profile```

Comment: I see. I was searching by the name so there was no hit.

Comment: Yeah I've got an instance profile which I can see on the CLI but not in the console

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't find the instance profile in the IAM section in the console as described by Slushysnowman.

This solved my issue:

```bash
aws iam delete-instance-profile --instance-profile-name 'your-profile-name'
```

Comment: This is more accurate than the accepted answer. An instance profile doesn't show up in the console, but it does exist under the hood and can be found via the CLI. If you manually are deleting resources that are conflicting with some sort of IaC (terraform) this will still cause conflict in the case of the same name being in use by what your IaC is trying to create and what you already have created.

Comment: bang on. I faced this issue when I removed the role before terminating the instance. It broke all my code and was unable to find it on the console. By removing it with aws cli, It went fine